# AppleScript - Change all app icons in a directory

Tags: applescript

I have folders containing applications. I want to be able to select the folder with an apple script, and have the script go through each app file in that directory, changing the icons for me.

I want to have the icon set from an image stored in the script directory.

I'd really appreciate any help because I've been trying to make this work for a while. This is my progress so far:

```
property appcurrentCount : 0
on run
set theFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Select the start folder")
doSomethingWith(theFolder)
end run
on doSomethingWith(aFolder)
tell application "Finder"
 set subApps to every file of aFolder
 repeat with eachFolder in subApps

-- replace icon here somehow

 end repeat
end tell

display dialog "Count is now " & appcurrentCount & "."
end doSomethingWith
```

Comment: Icons of application must be '.icns' format and are located in application/Contents/Resources folder. icns are not really images format, but something more complex (set of predefined set of  sizes of the image). The second issue is that App/Contents/Resources may contains several icons (for the app itself, for some dialogs, documents,...). Then it will not be easy to define which one to be changed. For instance, Microsoft Word contains 50 icns in this Resources folder. Are you sure to go in that direction ?

Comment: That's okay, because all of my programs I'll be editing only contain one icns file. I'd really appreciate it if you could show me how! :D Thanks again pbell!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script bellow does now what you want. As explained before, your icon file must be type icns. I now add this filter directly in the choose file command.

The selected icon will now replace ALL icons already in each Contents/Resources folder of all applications in the selected folder.
The replacement will be done preserving the name of the icns already in place.

Warning : there is no 'undo' command. your old icons are overwritten !!

```
set Myicon to choose file with prompt "Select Icns to be copied in every Application of the folder" of type "com.apple.icns"
set MyFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select the folder with all applications to be changed"
set Source to POSIX path of Myicon -- convert path to unix form

tell application "Finder"
set MyApps to every item of MyFolder whose name extension is "app"
display dialog "count apps=" & count of MyApps
repeat with anAps in MyApps -- loop for each App
    set IcnFolder to ((anAps as string) & ":Contents:Resources:") as alias
    set MyIcns to (every item of IcnFolder whose name extension is "icns")
    display dialog "count of icn in " & alaps & " = " & (count of MyIcns)
    repeat with oneIcon in MyIcns -- loop for each icns
set Destination to POSIX path of (oneIcon as string)
        try
            do shell script "cp " & (quoted form of Source) & " " & (quoted form of Destination)
        end try
    end repeat -- loop for each icns
end repeat -- loop for each App
end tell
```

Comment: It works well, but I'd like it to replace the icons of the current .icns files. Do you think you could tweak it for me to overwrite every existing icns file? Thank you very much pbell!

Comment: you said that the ice in each application paquet have always the same name ?

Comment: current scripts overwrite the icns with name icnName. if not, how to find the correct name of the Icns in the application paquet ?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't mean that. Each application will have different icns names. I just want any icns file in every app to be replaced by the new one, sustaining the old name.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing pbell :/ I must've wrote it wrong

Comment: Script updated. I tested it on my side and OK. still, I advice you to copy your folder containing all your application before changing (backup is our friend !)

Comment: Thank you very much pbell! I'll test it Monday to see if it's all as expected, and then I'll mark it as correct answer :D Thank you very much!

Comment: I just tested it today, it works quite well! However, finder crashes about halfway through if there are too many icons to change :( It just says it's not responding.

Comment: Do you think you could fix that for me please? :) Thank you very much pbell!

Comment: How Apps do you have in the folder ? how many icons in each apps. It could help me to propose solution. may be you should select only 1 app for each run ?

Comment: I might do, but it's a lot easier to do them all. Probably around 50, but I'm not sure. It's just a lot and I think it works but it gives up after it remains unresponsive while it works for a while.

Comment: I sut update the script to add 2 display dialogs to show the number of apps and number of icns in each app. 50 Aps is not that big then it should be OK for a script. I already had scripts with hundred of files. Please use the script (you have to hit enter for each dialog), but it will help to see why it fails.

Comment: Don't worry I haven't forgotten about your answer :) I will soon be able to test it and mark it as correct pbell!